# D3.js line transition is going out of the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a line graph where I have line transition. However on the initial graph drawing line path is ok, within the graph. But when I use the transition the line goes out of the container to the margins.

**Transition function:**

```
that.graph.select('.data-line')
     .transition().duration(750)
     .attr('fill', 'none')
     .attr('stroke', '#ff0000')
     .attr('stroke-width', 2)
     .attr('d', line);
```

**Line:**

```
const line = d3.line()
     .x(d => xAxis(new Date(d.n)))
     .y(d => yAxis(d.v))
     .defined(d => d.v || d.v === 0);
```

**Axes:**

```
const xAxis = d3.scaleTime()
                .range([0, width])
                .domain(xDomain);

const yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([height, 0])
                .domain(yDomain);
```

**Domains:**

```
const yDomain = d3.extent(data, d => d.v);
const xDomain = d3.extent(data, d => new Date(d.n));
```

**Dimensions:**

```
const width = window.innerWidth - this.margins.left - this.margins.right;
const height = window.innerHeight - this.margins.top - this.margins.bottom;
```

**Initial line drawing:** (this is ok)

```
this.graph.append('g').attr('class', 'data-wrapper');

const line = d3.line()
                .x(d => this.xAxis(new Date(d.n)))
                .y(d => this.yAxis(d.v))
                .defined(d => d.v || d.v === 0);

this.graph
     .select('.data-wrapper')
     .append('path')
     .datum(data)
     .attr('class', 'data-line')
     .attr('fill', 'none')
     .attr('stroke', '#ff0000')
     .attr('stroke-width', 2)
     .attr('d', line);
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add a clipping region or remove the data points outside your domain

Comment: @rioV8 Thx, this solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rioV8 suggested adding clip path solved issue.

If anyone in the feature has this problem here is the solution:
On your topmost SVG add this:

```
  this.graph.append('defs')
                .append('clipPath')
                .attr('id', 'clip')
                .append('rect')
                .attr('width', this.width)
                .attr('height', this.height);
```

And on the function where you draw data add

```
.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
```